# Can you update node:latest

Tags: node.js, docker

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /app/templates
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY *.js /app/
RUN npm install npm@latest -g

CMD     ["node","/app/index.js"]
```

From the above Dockerfile is there any way to update node like when you update Ubuntu or apt-get update?

Or, is npm all you can really control?

Comment: The node:latest is the latest node version available on DockerHub. You can try `docker pull node:latest` to update your local image. Assuming you're getting the latest version 8.

Comment: Sidenote: Latest may abruptly change, and hence it is more stable to pinpoint certain version of an image. E.g. `node:6.11` for lts or `node:8.4` if you want to be bleeding edge. Using latest might make you build fail on a future update with breaking changes. See the tags section on the node image for reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Answer (score 2):

As Russley Shaw said, `docker pull node:latest` will download the most recent `node:latest` image from [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) and if the downloaded image is different from your local one, it will overwrite your local `node:latest` image with the newer downloaded one. Then, when you do a `docker build`, Docker will recognize that `node:latest` has changed (assuming that your `docker pull node:latest` updated your local image). Then, Docker will invalidate all its caches used in building the container  and rebuild it starting from the very first Dockerfile instruction at

```
FROM node:latest
```

You can check when the Node team last pushed a new image to DockerHub on their DockerHub repo page I believe.

Comment: Alternatively, `docker build . --pull` will also pull a new image from the remote.